# PHP: downloading a file on password-protected page

Tags: php, authentication

So i've made a php script which allows me to download some specific files from another password-protected webpage using basic http-authentication, where I simply put the username and password in the URL like username:password@url.com. It works without problems, but i'm having trouble figuring out how to do the same thing on a webpage with cookie-session based authentication. In short, when a user goes to my PHP-webpage, they should be redirected to the login-form of the external webpage, then redirected back to my PHP-webpage. At this point my script should be able to communicate with the external webpage using the users credentials. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This can't work. Cookies are per-domain, you can't read a cookie from another domain.

Comment: it can be done, but it requires a socket to socket connection to obtain the authentication ticket from the 3rd party server using an ID.  It generally uses a horrible library called easyXDM.  If you have a look at ubisofts authentication on every one of their implimentations they do this (even when theyre not x-domain), much to the annoyance of anyone that has to professionally interact with them through an api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to simulate requests to the password protected site's login form (while maintaining the cookie send in response - this would probably contain identifier of session, which is used to handle logged-in user's identity). Then you will request to download the file from the protected site, while sending the cookie from login response along.